# C# SQL database console application

Tags: c#, .net, sql, mysql

I'm not very familiar with the console application but i think its kind a interesting subject to learned. I searched for tutorials and references related to connecting MySQL database in console but no luck. So i just try and error. **Please correct me I'm wrong..**

I had an application where when user run the program, it'll store values to database. In the Form Application, it runs well(no doubt). Now with the same approach, i want it to be run it in the console application. So, I create new project in console and just copy, do some editing on the codes and put in Main. Luckily, the code running well.

**My concerns are, is it what i'm doing is write? the command for the form can be used in console? What are differences between this two? is this the better approached?**

**Any advice and references are very helpful.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Console applications are typically designed without  a graphical user interface. A console application is run from the command line with input and output information being exchanged between to and from the console window, this makes the console application **a great way to learn new programming technique** without having to be concerned with the user interface.

Answer (score 3):

There's very little difference between console apps and WinForms apps in terms of the pieces of code which actually interact with the database.

One significant difference between them in the *surrounding* code is that you'd usually use a different thread to perform the database access in a WinForms app, to avoid blocking the UI thread. If you're just writing the data out to a console, there's no need for that.

Comment: Ok, thx all...what I'm understand now, there are no much different in code but only in term of UI. On what u said, "There's very little difference between console apps and WinForms apps in terms of the pieces of code which actually interact with the database." Can u show me some example codes on How and What is the best solution of it in console application.

Comment: (p/s:Example code in Winform.I did tried copy,paste,n run the code in console n it run's well too)
//create connection        
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection con;
DataSet ds1;
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter da;
//in FormLoad() open connection
con = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection();
ds1 = new DataSet();
con.ConnectionString = "<dbase path>
con.Open();
//insert command
String sInsert = "INSERT INTO tblOutbox (ip_addr, message,date)" + VALUES( 'value1', 'value2', 'date')";
da = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter(sInsert, con);
da.Fill(ds1, "tblOutbox");
//close con