# C# Console Application with SQL Database

Tags: c#, database

I have a Visual C# Console Application (Eventually I will add some graphics). I would like to integrate this project with a database with the following functionality:

1. During execution the program shall be able to write data to the database
2. During execution the program shall be able to read data from the database
3. The database shall be stored on a server (Locally will do for now)

How can I obtain this functionality in Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate?
(If you need more information let me know)

What "item" should I add to my project in Visual Studio so that I can write SQL statements with query strings?

Over time I would like to be able to store thousands of records to an online database.
Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried?  This is so simple to do, you are sure to pick up down votes.  There are plenty of walkthroughs for this.

Comment: I just do not know what the best 'item' to add in Visual Studio is.

Comment: There's absolutely no difference in connecting to and using a database between WinForm and console applications; you just do it without the graphical user interface. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1287018/62576) to a very similar question (found in the `Related` list to the right of your question, which means you should have found it even without a search, BTW).

Comment: You don't add anything visually in VS. You create everything yourself in code (declaring variables in your class to hold them). The whole point of a console app is you don't have a GUI, which means you have nothing to drop "items" on.

Comment: @GrayFox374 If this is such a simple question, answer it. Maybe I am not conveying my question accurately.

Comment: @Ken White look at one of my edits. I definitely need a database, I just do not know how to access one through Visual Studio in C#. (Setting up a connection, using query strings, and processing a result set)

Comment: You're not.  We don't know what you are working with.  What database do you have?  What servers do you have?  When you say online database, what does that mean? Over an Intranet? Over the Internet?  Put some meet on the bones dude.

Comment: I saw your edits, and gave you the info in my last comment. "You create everything yourself in code" (the connection, the queries, processing the result set - **everything** is done in code. The number of "records" (rows) you want to store is irrelevant.

Comment: @Ken White If you will elaborate with some specific instructions including a few references, you will have a great answer.

Comment: A local database stored on my machine will do for now... However the idea is that I could simply export my local database onto a server.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I'm not going to write actual code for you, because I don't see any indication you've tried to do this yourself first. Here are the basic steps involved, though:

1. Add references to `System.Data`, `System.Data.Common`, and `System.Data.SqlClient` to your project.
2. Declare member (class) variables to hold references to an `SqlAdapter`, `SqlConnection`, and `SqlCommand`.
3. Create each of the above in your class constructor or initialization method, setting the properties as needed for each (for instance, `SqlConnection` requires that you provide a value for `ConnectionString`, and `SqlCommand` need `CommandType` and `CommandText` values, and so forth).
4. Use the above member variables to access data just like you would in a GUI app, except you have no UI controls to use to display the data - all data access is via your code.

For specific ways to set things up, create a standard WinForms application and set up your database connection, query, and so forth. Look at the variables that VS creates to hold each of them, and how they're initialized in `InitializeComponents` - you need to perform those same steps yourself in your code instead of via dragging and dropping things in the VS user interface.

This should be enough to get you started. Once you've tried, you can post any questions related to specific issues as new questions here on SO.